# setting status of a build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, devops

I have a jenkins job.
It is pretty simple: pull from git, and run the build.

The build is just one step:

**Execute window command batch**

In my use case, I will need to run some python scripts.
Some will fail, some others will not.

```
python a.py
python b.py
```

What does determine the final status of the build?
It seems I can edit that by:

```
echo @STABLE > build.proprieties
```

but how are the STABLE/UNSTABLE status assigned if not specified by the user?
What happens if b.py raise an error and fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins interprets a pipeline as failed if a command returns an exit code unequal zero.

Internally the build status is set with `currentBuild.currentResult` which can have three values: `SUCCESS`, `UNSTABLE`, or `FAILURE`.

If you want to control the failure / success of your pipeline yourself you can catch exceptions / exit codes and manually set the value for `currentBuild.currentResult`. Plugins also use this attribute to change the result of the pipeline.

For example:

```
stage {
 steps {
  script {
    try {
        sh "exit 1" // will fail the pipeline
        sh "exit 0" // would be marked as passed
        currentBuild.currentResult = 'SUCCESS'
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentBuild.currentResult = 'FAILURE'
        // or currentBuild.currentResult = 'UNSTABLE'
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: only if an exit code unequal zero is returned. If a script returns a 2 the stage will also be marked as failed. Only a return value of 0 lets Jenkins mark the stage as a success so a return value is something you could consider in your scripts.